# Getting error "Cannot read property 'url' of undefined" when data is present

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I keep getting this error from a  tag when attempting to render a component which looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="playlists" class="playlists">
      <router-link
        :to="`/playlist/${playlist.id}`"
        tag="div"
        v-for="playlist in playlists"
        :key="playlist.id"
        class="playlist"
      >
        <img :src="playlist.images[0].url" alt="bild">
        <h2>{{playlist.name.toUpperCase()}}</h2>
      </router-link>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      playlists: null
    };
  },
  beforeMount: function() {
    if (this.$parent.$parent.loggedIn) {
      this.spotify.getUserPlaylists().then(data => {
        this.playlists = data.body.items;
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

All the data is present and I can render out the `playlist.images[0]` object but when attempting to render `playlist.images[0].url` it gives me the error. 
The image array looks like this:

```
"images": [
        {
            "height": null,
            "url": "www.example.com",
            "width": null
        }
 ]
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Render `<img>` when `playlist` is updated with API response:

change

```
<img :src="playlist.images[0].url" alt="bild">
```

to

```
<img v-if="playlist.images.length > 0" :src="playlist.images[0].url" alt="bild">
```